# How do I get the length of a file with a path longer than 260 characters?

Tags: c#, windows, path

I am trying to find especially large files on a file share with deeply nested folders.  They aren't my folders, so I don't get to rearrange them.  The usual way to get the length of a file is:

```
string fullPath = "C:\path\file.ext";
FileInfo info = new FileInfo(fullPath);
long len = info.Length;
```

If the length of the path is greater than 260 characters, the FileInfo constructor throws a PathTooLongException.  I've read the Kim Hamilton blog entries on long file paths in .NET, so I know it can be done if I ditch the framework and do it all with Win32 API calls.  Is there a way to do it with the framework?

Kim Hamilton blog entries on long file paths in .NET:
[Part 1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/bclteam/long-paths-in-net-part-1-of-3-kim-hamilton)
[Part 2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/bclteam/)
[Part 3](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/bclteam/)

Comment: the following might be part of your solution: is it possible for you have those servers enable 8.3 filenames on the server? 
this allows to use ~
here is a bit of info http://www.m86security.com/kb/article.aspx?id=12180

Comment: Would it be too expensive to just read in the file and count the number of bytes?

Comment: I am scanning half a million files that average 100 MB. A significant number are in the multi-GB range. The selected answer works quite well and is fast.

Comment: According to Jeremy Kuhne the problem is being worked and may soon have a solution.  See this video. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZppqEMegCAA

Comment: [.NET 4.6.2 seems to support long paths natively](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2016/08/02/announcing-net-framework-4-6-2/). To me, it looks like this feature is [not yet ready for prime time](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/jeremykuhne/2016/07/30/net-4-6-2-and-long-paths-on-windows-10/).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check out the BCL Codeplex site, they have a future extension which might help you now:

http://bcl.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Long%20Path

Comment: This did the trick, Although it did require using VS 2010 and framework 4.

Comment: Also, the Long Path library doesn't properly support UNC paths.

Comment: Ugh. At least there is an outstanding issue with a good number of votes: http://bcl.codeplex.com/workitem/7589

Answer (score 3):

Windows does support paths longer than 260. However, this functionality is not exposed through .NET directly. To get the length of a file with path longer than 260, use the [GetFileAttributesEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa364944(VS.85).aspx) Windows API function which can be accessed in .NET through marshalling:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct WIN32_FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DATA
{
    public FileAttributes dwFileAttributes;
    public FILETIME ftCreationTime;
    public FILETIME ftLastAccessTime;
    public FILETIME ftLastWriteTime;
    public uint nFileSizeHigh;
    public uint nFileSizeLow;
}

public enum GET_FILEEX_INFO_LEVELS {
    GetFileExInfoStandard,
    GetFileExMaxInfoLevel
}

public class MyClass
{
    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError=true, CharSet=CharSet.Unicode)]
    private static extern bool GetFileAttributesEx(string lpFileName,
          GET_FILEEX_INFO_LEVELS fInfoLevelId, out WIN32_FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DATA fileData);

    public static long GetFileLength(string path)
    {
         // Check path here

         WIN32_FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DATA fileData;

         // Append special suffix \\?\ to allow path lengths up to 32767
         path = "\\\\?\\" + path;

         if(!GetFileAttributesEx(path,
                 GET_FILEEX_INFO_LEVELS.GetFileExInfoStandard, out fileData))
         {
               throw new Win32Exception();
         }
         return (long)(((ulong)fileData.nFileSizeHigh << 32) +
                        (ulong)fileData.nFileSizeLow);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try out the Zeta Long Paths library: http://zetalongpaths.codeplex.com/

Comment: My [Zeta Long Paths library is now available on GitHub](https://github.com/UweKeim/ZetaLongPaths).

Answer (score 0):

Works with the `Microsoft Scripting Runtime` COM reference

```
var fso = new Scripting.FileSystemObject();
double fileSize = fso.GetFile(path).Size;  // path is over 300 chars
```